# Regression modeling of differences-in-differences in Stata

Tags: stata, difference-in-difference

I'm having some trouble fitting a model for differences-in-differences regression in Stata. Specifically, I'm confused as to the `B3` coefficient in the below:

```
y = B0 + B1p + B2trt + B3(p*trt) + u
```

Here, `p` and `trt` are dummy variables where `p = 0` for pre-treatment and `1` for post-treatment, and `trt = 0` for control group and `1` for treatment group. `p * trt` is an interaction term indicating the marginal impact of the treatment group over the experimental period.

My question is whether this should be a simple dummy variable equal to zero if either `p / trt = 0` and `1` if both `p / trt = 1`?

Comment: By construction the interaction of $p\cdot trt=1$ if both $p=1$ and $trt=1$. The coefficient $B3$ gives you the difference in differences estimate.

Comment: Thanks, Andy. And then if either $p=0$ or $t=0$ then $p*t=0$, correct?

Comment: That is correct